# Custom WindowToolbar for my stylesheet

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet, customization

So I've noticed that some stylesheets (for instance Slideshow stylesheets) load a toolbar using the assignment `WindowToolbars -> {"ToolbarName"}` and I've been wondering whether it's possible to prepare and load a custom one using this mechanism.

I've searched Mathematica directories but I couldn't find the toolbars source directory.

Comment: In case it matters: which version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: I'm using v10 and v9.

Comment: I think what you need to do is create a customized `DockedCell` with the functionality that you want and include that in your stylesheet.

Comment: I've been using `DockedCell`, but it'd be better to use WindowToolbars

Comment: @Ranza Why WindowToolbars  are better?

Comment: @Kuba well, for one it looks better and mirrors a native toolbar. It'd be best to have a Toolbar with generic notebook functions and a more specialized DockedCell